# Check if path under app-scoped bookmark is writable inside sandboxed app

Tags: objective-c, swift, security, sandbox, appstore-sandbox

I have an OS X app, which stores an app-scoped bookmark to persist access to certain directories. I am able to write to those directories without any problems, but there is a part in my code where I want to make an extra check to confirm that the path is writable and it fails.

```
var fileManager: NSFileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
var baseUrl: NSURL = try! NSURL(byResolvingBookmarkData: data, …)
var fileUrl: NSURL = url.URLByAppendingPathComponent("foo.txt")

// Changing this order has no effect, I make only the first start access call,
// the second one is to demonstrate that it's not working.

baseUrl.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() // true
fileUrl.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() // false

// File manager confirms that base path is writable, but anything inside
// it – not. This worked perfectly fine before sandboxing the app.

fileManager.isWritableFileAtPath(baseUrl.path!) // true
fileManager.isWritableFileAtPath(fileUrl.path!) // false

// Writing file to the `fileUrl` works anyway, even though
// file manager thinks it's not writable.

writeMyFile(toUrl: fileUrl)

// Here's another interesting observation, is writable starts working
// once the files get created.

fileManager.isWritableFileAtPath(fileUrl.path!) // false
fileManager.createFileAtPath(fileUrl.path!, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
fileManager.isWritableFileAtPath(fileUrl.path!) // true
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there a problem with file manager inside a sandbox? Is there a decent way to check if subpath is writable, i.e., without creating files?

Comment: it looks to me as expected. as long as the file doesn't exist, there is nothing to read from and write to and therefore no access granted. Did you try using NSURLKeys? 
NSURLIsReadableKey  in NSURL - (BOOL)getResourceValue:(out id *)value forKey:(NSString *)key

Comment: Starting accessing it isn't a point, I've put it just to demonstrate that using it makes no diff. The key point is that `isWritableFileAtPath` returning `false`, while path is actually writable. There is some truth in "no file = no writable", but in non-sandboxed environment it works fine for non-existing files and I've learned to expect it to work like this de facto. Seems like a decent solution to check behind the scenes if directory is writable and return `true` for non-existing files in sandbox. Instead, it looks like now this must be done by hand every time.

Comment: @IanBytchek - any luck finding a solution? I'm running into the exact same issue.

Comment: @kev no, no luck… I've banged my head on the wall for a few days testing everything that I could find and gave up into using `try catch` and other checks where necessary. Sandboxing comes with some f-up cases, I'm using `-DSANDBOX` compiler flag to handle some such cases differently. Apart from that can't advise anything else. If you go the hard way and find a solution, please share! :)

Comment: @IanBytchek If you only start access to the file if it is not readable, does that do the trick for you? `if let path = url?.path where NSFileManager.defaultManager().isReadableFileAtPath(path) == false {
    url?.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource();
}`

Comment: I'll have to try. Did that work? Does isWritableFileAtPath also work?