# How can I test whether I can read or write a directory?

Tags: swift, macos, file-handling, appstore-sandbox

I am writing an app which will be sandboxed when I finish with it. For now it’s not.

The app will copy files from one location to another. Because it’s not currently sandboxed, I can preset the directories and go ahead.

When it’s sandboxed, I won’t be able to do that until I manually select the two locations. Without selecting the two locations, the code quietly doesn’t work.

I can’t find anything which lets me know whether I can go ahead. Is there some sort of status I can examine?

Comment: How are you selecting files?  If you use `NSOpenPanel`, you can tell that a file has been selected, right?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35307603/check-if-path-under-app-scoped-bookmark-is-writable-inside-sandboxed-app - the question code and the question comments may be helpful. It is an outdated version of Swift though.

Comment: @ElTomato When relaunching the app, I use `@AppStorage` to repopulate the directory, but that’s not enough to allow the copy to proceed. I’ve since then found a way of testing the directory, as well as adding a bookmark for subsequent launches.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something simple like this example code.

Change the `File Access Type` in your `App Sandbox` and see the changes.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let path = "/Users/THE-USER/Downloads/testFile.txt"
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(path).foregroundStyle(.blue)
        Text("FREAD: \(checkFile(FREAD))")
        Text("FWRITE: \(checkFile(FWRITE))")
        Text("O_RDONLY: \(checkFile(O_RDONLY))")
        Text("O_RDWR: \(checkFile(O_RDWR))")
    }
    
    func checkFile(_ flag: Int32) -> Int32 {
        let thePath = (path as NSString)
        return open(thePath.fileSystemRepresentation, flag)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, the solution is to use `FileManager.default.isReadableFile(atPath: …)`.

Here’s a simple application of it:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var dir: String? = "."
    @State var dirOK = false
    

    var body: some View {
        return VStack {
            Button(action: {
                dir = selectFolder(title: "Open …", directoryURL: dir ?? ".")
                dirOK = dir != nil && FileManager.default.isReadableFile(atPath: dir!)
            }) {
                Text("Open …")
            }
            Text(dir!)
            Text(dirOK ? "Ok" : "no")
        }.onAppear() {
            dirOK = dir != nil && FileManager.default.isReadableFile(atPath: dir!)
        }
    }
}
```

Assume that there’s a function called `selectFolder()`.

If the app is sandboxed, `dirOK` is false until you select a directory. If it’s not sandboxed, and `dir` refers to a valid directory, `dirOK` is true.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to check for writing permission.

In a sandboxed environment if the locations are outside the application container it is required that the user selects the locations before accessing them.

Another requirement is that `User Selected File` must be set to `Read/Write` in the sandbox entitlements.

1. If a location is supposed to be permanent (across application relaunch) create a security scoped bookmark and ***resolve*** it on launch. If it fails ask the user again to select the location. To be able to write into the location you have to call `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` and `stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource` before and after the writing operation.
2. Otherwise ask the user for the locations on launch or just before the move operation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wanted to test the directory’s readability so that I can use it to change the appearance and disable the button. However, I didn’t know about scoped bookmarks. I’ve since added that to my app, so I have the best of both worlds.

Comment: You need to test whether the bookmark is valid which is called *resolving* the bookmark. The sandbox rules are pretty clear.