# How to create an alias into a directory with denied permission

Tags: objective-c, macos

Trying to create some alias file into a directory, but I got NSCocoaErrorDomain - code: 512. I have read and write access to the source directory, but no write access to the destination directory.

Source directory:
- source file

Destination directory:
- alias (links to the source file)

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [src bookmarkDataWithOptions:NSURLBookmarkCreationWithSecurityScope
                        includingResourceValuesForKeys:nil
                                         relativeToURL:nil
                                                 error:&error];
if(data != nil)
    [NSURL writeBookmarkData:data toURL:dest options:NSURLBookmarkCreationWithSecurityScope error:&error];
```

If I create a folder or a file manually inside the destination directory, OS X asks me for the admin password:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711049/creating-a-security-scope-bookmark-for-a-file-from-one-of-a-directory-containing

Comment: @johnelemans don't see how this should help me =( I only found a way to execute some apple script with administration privileges http://stackoverflow.com/a/8865284/4299534 but there must be a way to do it with objective-c

Comment: Does somebody has experience with https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/